# How to make a batch file recognize the enter key?

Tags: batch-file

I have my file doing a looping animation and I have it set up to get out of the loop when I press 1. How do I change the 1 to the enter key?
Here's the code:

```
choice /c 1c /t 1 /d c >null

if %errorlevel% == 1 goto menu

goto tie
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Try the keyreader.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/keyreader.bat).It will read a single keystroke (with optional timeout) and will return its char code to the error level.
and you can use this:

```
call keyreader.bat 1000
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto :tie
if %errorlevel% equ 13 ( 
   echo enter was pressed
   goto :menu
)
```

Comment: What do I replace "call keyreader.bat
if %errorlevel% equ 13 echo enter was pressed" with?

Comment: @tigey101 - what do you want to happen when the enter is pressed? And what to happen when other key is pressed?

Comment: Right now if no key is pressed it continues the loop by going to :tie and if 1 is pressed it goes to :menu. I want to make it so instead of 1, enter is pressed to make it go to menu

Comment: @tigey101 - you need an key reader with timeout.Check my edit.